# Why does рот become рту, in the Dative Case?

Tags: окончания, беглая-гласная

What is the reason for this change? I had been under the impression that the rules from this (http://www.russianlessons.net/grammar/nouns_dative.php) page apply to the changing of the noun ending.

Comment: рот in Dative is рту, not рта.

Comment: It's also prepositional, being one of the nouns that take stressed -у for that case: во рту

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, your page doesn't mention this important phenomenon which is called *беглая гласная* '[a fleeting vowel](http://www.public.asu.edu/%7Edeliving/russgram/fvover.htm).' The thing is like this: in some words, the stressed vowels **o**, **e**, and **ё** completely disappear, turn to null, when the form of the word changes and the stress moves onto another vowel. Your noun *рот* has its root stressed, but when we form the Genitive case and add the ending *-a*, the stress moves onto this ending and the *-o-* in the root disappears.

The fleeting vowels are met very often in Russian and also in all the other Slavic languages, that's a common-Slavic phenomenon. But note, not every **o**, **e**, and **ё** is fleeting, e.g.:

> кóт — котá : no vowel disappears.

But:

> сóн — снá
>
> бeрý — брáть
>
> звонóк — звонкá

You have to remember in which words the vowel disappears, a good dictionary marks such words and their forms.

The reason why these vowels disappear is that the ones that do, descend from the ancient very short, reduced, vowels known as [*yers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yer): a short high front vowel denoted as *ĭ* or *ь*, and a short back vowel denoted as *ŭ* or *ъ*. These vowels underwent reduction and were eventually deleted in certain positions in a word in the early Slavic languages, but if they were in a stressed position, they changed into the full vowels, in Russian into **e** and **o** respectfully. This phenomenon is called [Havlík's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havl%C3%ADk%27s_law).

And again, note, *рта* is not the Dative case, it is the Genitive case of *рот*, the Dative case from this noun is *рту*.

Comment: +1. I believe the English term is "fleeting vowel".

Comment: @Quassnoi - Haha, really! Thank you, I corrected it.

Comment: It's "берý", not "бéру".